# How to compare String Variable with Integer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table structure and and some sample data. I want return data for multiple ids via parameter. I have declared a parameter string and now I want to compare it with the column but it ain't allowing because ID is integer.
Can anybody give me any help here ?

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    ID INT,
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1, 'Isaac Frempong');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2, 'Eric Ortizz');

DECLARE @StrID VARCHAR(20) = '1, 2'
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ID = @StrID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE @StrID+',' LIKE '%'+cast(ID as varchar(20))+'%,'
```

Pretty bad performance as it will need to do a table scan but safe enough.

Generally though, your list of IDs should be a table variable you can do a proper `JOIN` or `IN` with

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000) = 'SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID IN (' + @StrID + ')';
EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: While it is simple indeed please bear in mind that this makes you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @MatthiasMeid Maybe, if it were open to outside users, this is entirely written by OP, so unless he wants to attack himself, he's safe :)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2017+ you could use `STRING_SPLIT` a table-valued function that splits a string into rows of substrings

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
ID INT,
EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1, 'Isaac Frempong');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2, 'Eric Ortizz');

DECLARE @StrID VARCHAR(20) = '1, 2'
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT (@StrID,','))
```

Refer this working [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=33daa9f9fd144a0c07b1afdd9d8f0169)

Answer (score 1):

Create a user defined table type and pass it as a parameter.

```
CREATE TYPE [UDT_INTIDS] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL
)
GO

-- create a table value
DECLARE @IDs [UDT_INTIDS];
INSERT @IDs VALUES (1),(2);

-- search using table value. 
SELECT e.* 
FROM EMPLOYEE e
WHERE e.ID IN (SELECT p.ID FROM @IDs p);
-- or
SELECT e.* 
FROM EMPLOYEE e
JOIN @IDs p ON e.ID = p.ID;
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Cast` in `SQL-Server` to cast it to the appropriate datatype. Source [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
WHERE CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(20)) = @StrID
```

**Alternatively:** You can use `CONVERT` function.

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ID) = @StrID
```